# Unable to display uploaded image - laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, image-uploading

I am able to get the file uploaded in server but the file is not displayed in the view. I checked the chrome console network tab and it seems while fetching the file system is getting exception **404 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 179)**.

Below is my **filesystem.php** configuration:

```
//filesystem.php
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),
.
.
.
.
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],
```

Here is the excerpt from the controller where i am storing the file:

```
//file:AvatarController.php
$new_file_name = Storage::disk('public')
                 ->putFile('avatars',$request->file('avatar'));
```

I can see the file in the **Storage/app/public/avatars** folder which means file upload is successful. But the file is not being loaded in the view. The image element has the href attribute:

```
<img src="http://tddforum.com/avatars/Aew15JlTZAIrldYR6gXyFJ0lriK4p1vhVNim5oBo.jpeg" alt="johnDoe" with="100" height="100">
```

I have also created the symbolic link between the **public** folder and the **Storage/app** folder

What am i doing wrong here? Please let me know if you need any more inforation.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried in your view in img src attributes `{{ asset('storage/avatars/Aew15JlTZAIrldYR6gXyFJ0lriK4p1vhVNim5oBo.jepg') }}`

Comment: This works. Thanks!! Wondering should i also prepend _storage/_ to the path while i save it to the database? In the TDD series in laracast jeffry did not add _storage_. he just did <img src="{{ asset($user->avatar_location) }}">!!

Comment: Well i didn't watch the series but are you sure that he uploaded the avatar in storage folder not in public folder ? , and for database , no you don't have to do that .

Comment: Yes i am 100% sure! He is storing the files in **storage/app/public/avatars** folder! He is using the 'local' disk whereas i am using the 'public' disk, that is the only difference. And the reason i am thinking of saving it into DB with _storage/_ prepended is because now i it's saving as **avatars/(filename)** whereas to show it from my view i have to append **storage/**. This behavior seems weird, don't you think?